# Get result from a function more than once may cause this function to do query again?

Tags: php

I have a function to run a query from database. Then, it will be called by 2 other functions.

```
function query(){
 $query= // get data from database;
return $query;
}

function show_something(){
$data = query();
//do something
}

function show_else(){
$data = query();
//do something else
}
```

The function query() is called twice. I guess it would do the query job every time the function is called unless the result is cached. Would anybody correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do something like this:

- Set an indicator to mark if the query is first or repeated.
- Before querying, check indicator.

**Code:**

```
$fresh = true; // fresh results wanted
function query(){
global $fresh;
if($fresh){
     $query= // get data from database;
     $bar = $query; // cache the $query value for next uses..
     $$fresh = false; // set the indicator that query is cached.
}else{ // this is repeated query
    $query = $bar; //we had set the $bar last time
}
return $query;
}

function show_something(){
//first time query, $query will be fetched from database,
// also $fresh will be set to false
$data = query();
//do something
}

function show_else(){
//repeated query, cached value will be returned.
$data = query();
//do something else
}

$foo = true; // if you want fresh results, set $fresh to true before query
function show_fresh(){
//results will be fresh, because we have set $fresh to true again.
$data = query();
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be called twice. You can cache the result if you want, using static variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting the same query to be pulled each time (ie, no variables change) you might be better off using an object along these lines:

```
class checkSomethingOrOther
{
    public $myVariable;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->myVariable))
        {
            $this->myVariable=query();
        }
        return $this-myVariable;
    }
}
```

This will simply check to see if the variable is set, if not, it grabs the data and returns it, otherwise, just returns it.

Comment: I see. This way avoids database call every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is correct; your function unconditionally performs an explicit query, therefore it will perform it each time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

The database could have changed in between the function calls.  Even if they're called immediately one after the other.

So, yes, the query will run twice; because the result may be different.

Unless you implement some caching mechanism.